# ImportError: No module named bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I installed BeautifulSoup4 using pip in OSX but I yet get this error:

```
dyn-72-33-214-45:craiglist mona$ python t1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

Any idea how to fix it?

```
dyn-72-33-214-45:craiglist mona$ pip install BeautifulSoup4
....
Successfully installed BeautifulSoup4
Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 3):

I installed it using `easy_install` and now it is working. However first you should use `sudo su` :

```
dyn-72-33-214-45:craiglist mona$ sudo su
sh-3.2# easy_install beautifulsoup4
```